# Как выдать пользователю стейт по айди?

Tags: python, aiogram

Возник вопрос, нужно выдать определённый стейт двум пользователям по известным айди

Comment: дайте хотя бы примеры кода, модели которые используете, методы в которых хоть что то происходит

Comment: в тегах написало что используется фреймворк aiogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В aiogram установить состояние любого пользователя в любом чате можно с помощью следующей конструкции:

```
state = dp.current_state(chat=chat_id, user=user_id)
await state.set_state(User.accepted)
```

Где:

dp - объект класса Dispatcher

chat_id - id чата, который должен быть равен id пользователя, если это переписка с пользователем

User.accepted - состояние в которое мы хотим привести пользователя

Comment: а если нужно привести пользователя в лс в какое либо состояние, то что нужно писать в chat, а что в user

Comment: Если это ЛС бот-юзер то чат айди и юзер айди одно и тоже, то бишь и туда и туда пиши юзер айди

Comment: спасибо огромное, помогло

Comment: @addqwer234 в таком случае подтвердите ответ нажав на галочку под счётчиком слева от ответа